# TextView string displays operator at beginning of string instead of end

Tags: android, textview

Sorry guys if this is something basic, but i am new to Android dev and can't figure this one out on my own.

I am having an issue where i try to display a string such as "123+" in a TextView but it displays as "+123".

I print the string out to the console and it is displaying as "123+" but the TextView always moves the operator to the beginning of the string. Can anyone please explain why and how to prevent this from happening?

FYI i am setting the text using the TextView setText() method.

Eg:

```
String text = "123+";
tv.setText(text);
```

displays as +123 in the textview

Comment: have you tried convert the symbol into unicode?

Comment: As far as i am aware, all characters in java are unicode. But just to make sure, i just tried with a unicode symbol and the result is the same.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not your actual code since it sounds like you're building the text from user input rather than hard coding it.  How about the real code?

Answer (score 0):

String s=String.format("%i+",number);

actually i just don't know if this works but i've seen an example of this before

Comment: Thanks Farido but i am not trying to format a number with a "+" operator after the end, i am trying to build a simple calculator so when i input the expression 123+456, as i press the buttons on the calculator i will get the strings formatted as
"1"..
"12" ..
"123" .. 
"123+" ...
"123+4" etc. When i press the "=" symbol, the whole string will be sent as input to a parsing module.